# how to click on a link using its Name on the button

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

i'm trying to click on a link of attendance button on my dashboard, and on inspection it looks like this.

```
<li><a href="../Student/StudentAttendanceView.aspx?
SID=tfbtnuEqpDtgIR/2F6Ob/g==|DvMovYUQmfs=" id="aAttandance">Attendance</a></li>
```

I wrote the script to login the page and i want to click on the link by its name Attendance which is under the `li` tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re looking to really simulate a browser, you might want to look at `selenium` (http://www.seleniumhq.org/), which allows you to control a real web browser.

You also can use `mechanize` for that. It provides an easy way for interacting with websites (https://github.com/python-mechanize/mechanize).

Comment: i'm not using selenium actually and i'm using python 3.5.2

Comment: ```selenium``` supports python 3: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium or https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/Selenium.

Comment: i dont want to use real browser

Comment: @PaulNicolashunter You can click on the buttom and snif on the output packets, and check which request is made,
and then only simulate the request by yourself with the ```requests``` module.